# canOpenUrl - This app is not allowed to query for scheme instragram

Tags: ios, info-plist

Im trying to add the Instagram url to my app in iOS9 however I am getting the following warning:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instragram://media?id=MEDIA_ID" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme instragram"
```

However, Ive added the following to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in my `info.plist`;

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <string>instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID</string>//this one seems to be the issue
</array>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated?

**EDIT 1**

This is the code I am using to open instagram:

```
 NSURL * instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instragram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];//edit: note, to anyone copy pasting this code, please notice the typo OP has in the url, that being "instragram" instead of "instagram". This typo was discovered after this StackOverflow question was posted.
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    //do stuff
}
else{
    NSLog(@"NO instgram found");
}
```

based off this example.

Comment: Is it because you've written instragram instead of instagram?

Comment: @JamesP *slaps himself in the face* how did i miss that, but ive fixed it and the issue still remains.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

1. Your `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` entry should only have schemes. There's no point to the second entry.

   ```
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
       <string>instagram</string>
   </array>
   ```
2. Read the error. You are trying to open the URL with a typo in the scheme. Fix your reference to `instragram` in your call to `canOpenURL:`.

Comment: Thats embarrassing, i read the error message about 30 times and kept over looking it. The error is now gone. The first point is also correct, there was no need for the second entry.

Comment: It's like trying to proof read your own paper. It doesn't work. You keep seeing what you expect it to be, not what it really is.

Answer (score 10):

**For Facebook who's need:**

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: this does not answer the real question

Comment: facebook owns instgram.. cough

Answer (score 7):

Put only `<string>instagram</string>`. It's not necessary the full path but the base of the scheme url.