# Having Issue while sharing text/image to Pinterest from App.It gets redirected to App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, pinterest

Having problem while posting to pin interest from app.Before it was working fine,may be due to IOS9? Now its redirected to app store,even when the pinterest app is installed.
Error shown when posting image
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "pinit://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme pinit"

Anyone know what could be the issue?I have attached the code which has been added in info.plist

```
        <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <key>pinit</key>
        <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
        </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.xxx.xxxx</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
        <string>pinxxxxxx</string>
        </array>
        </dict>
```

Comment: i think this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870393/canopenurl-this-app-is-not-allowed-to-query-for-scheme-instragram-ios9

Comment: Fixed. <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>pinit</string>
    </array>