# How can I run a link to vimeo

Tags: ios, objective-c, vimeo

I have an iOS application and I have a link https://vimeo.com/33881529

When I click it and while having a Vimeo application on my iPhone, it opens it in the browser. I don't want that. I want the video to run from my application to vimeo application.

Edit:

```
- (IBAction)film:(id)sender {
    NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"vimeo://33881529"];
    NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vimeo.com/33881529"];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToAppURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToAppURL];
    } else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToWebURL];
    } }
```

Other EDIT

```
- (IBAction)vimeofilm:(id)sender {
    NSURL * vimeoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"vimeo://33881529"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:vimeoURL]) {
        //do stuff
    }
    else{
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vimeo.com/33881529"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your app is the link? How do you handle it? Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: I Edited it but it's not working as I want.

Comment: Do you see any messages in the console? Have you added `vimeo` to your Info.plist as one of the URL schemes that you are allowed to query?

Comment: Can you explain more, please?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870393/canopenurl-this-app-is-not-allowed-to-query-for-scheme-instragram-ios9 is relevant to your problem. Of course you would need to replace `instagram` with `vimeo`.

Comment: I'm kind of lost, I added an edit :/ It didn't work!

Comment: Did you look at the other question? Are you seeing messages in the debugger console about being unable to query the `vimeo` URL scheme?

Comment: This one? "<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>"

Comment: Yes but change `instagram` to `vimeo`.

Comment: I did, but I didn't know where to put the previous code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main question is about playing the video within your application. There are two possibilities that I can see here:

1. You load the URL within a WebView in your application. Technically, this will play the video within your app.
2. You create a HTML string with the below iFrame tag:

> < iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID" width="WIDTH" height="HEIGHT" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>

Replace the VIDEO_ID with your video ID. Once this HTML String is ready, load it into as HTML data in your WebView.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried but it didnt work because I tried it, can you please code the code for me?

Answer (score 2):

You can have the Vimeo application open and play the video with the help of [VIMDeeplink](https://github.com/vimeo/VIMDeeplink). It is an open-sourced helper library supporting both swift and Objective-C. You can use it to check if the Vimeo iOS app is installed, and depending on if it is you can use it to open the Vimeo video player for a specific video; if the Vimeo app is not installed you can use the library to view the listing in the App Store. The ReadMe is pretty thorough and should answer all questions regarding the use of the library.

Answer (score 1):

As i read on Vimeo github page, i found this solution:

**doc:**
https://github.com/vimeo/VIMDeeplink#swift-and-objc

**The Vimeo deeplink base URL is:** 
vimeo://app.vimeo.com

**Open the video player:**
let uri = "/videos/33881529"

so your code should be like this:

```
- (IBAction)film:(id)sender {

    NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"vimeo://app.vimeo.com/videos/33881529"];
    NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vimeo.com/33881529"];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToAppURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToAppURL];
    } else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToWebURL];
    }
 }
```

i've tried it and it works properly.

Thanks