# canOpenURL is getting failed but the open works for outlook iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, url-scheme

I too saw many stack overflow question related to my question , I have implemented all the things they have mentioned and still it doesn't work. Before flagging duplicate please kind go through my complete question and I have implemented all of the required changes.

I am trying to open the outlook mail client app from my app. Please find the below code

```
let url = URL(string: "ms-outlook://compose?to=Feedback@myDomain.com&subject=Mobile%20App%20Feedback")
     if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
    }
    else
    {
          AppDelegate.sharedDelegate().getRootViewController().showAlert(title: "Cannot send email", message: "There is no Outlook app installed on your device device.")
    }
```

I have also added ms-outlook in my plist too.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>ms-outlook</string>
</array>
```

I am getting the below error

```
"This app is not allowed to query for scheme ms-outlook"
```

I am testing in real device too. If I remove the canOpenURL check and directly open the url is working fine. I have no clue what I have been missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [canOpenUrl - This app is not allowed to query for scheme instragram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870393/canopenurl-this-app-is-not-allowed-to-query-for-scheme-instragram)

Comment: Or... in the code you posted, what is `urlScheme!`? If I replace that with `.canOpenURL(url!)` it works fine - I get a `failed for URL: "ms-outlook://...` error message and the `if` fails (as opposed to the `not allowed to query` message)

Comment: I have updated my question , typo error.

Comment: @DonMag : If my question is a duplicate , where is the answer that is missing.

Comment: If you use the *exact code* you have here (pasted, not re-typed) do you still get `not allowed to query`? If you change your `let url = ` line to a simple `"https://apple.com"` do you get the same `not allowed to query`?

Comment: After adding the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` section, I was able to open MS Outlook-3.8.1 on my iPhone. `This app is not allowed to query for scheme ms-outlook` error was removed. Thanks @Warrior for mentioning it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I came out with alternate option.

```
  let scheme : String = "ms-outlook://compose?to=Feedback@myDomain.com&subject=Mobile%20App%20Feedback"

    if let url = URL(string: scheme) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
            (success) in
            if (success)
            {
                print("Open \(scheme): \(success)")
            }
            else
            {
                AppDelegate.sharedDelegate().getRootViewController().showAlert(title: "Cannot send email", message: "There is no Outlook app installed on your device.")
            }
        })
    }
```